# organizing search results based on longest match

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table that contains project keywords. Each project has several keywords.

In the web application, a user can perform a search by entering multiple keywords to search for. If the user enters (for example) four keywords, I want to return the search result as a list of projects. The projects should be ordered based on the longest matches first. The first projects listed will the ones that matched on all four keywords, followed by projects that matched on three out of four keywords, etc.

What query can I write to return the results?

This is a rough idea of what I think the query would look like:

```
select projectID 
  from project_keyword 
 where keyword = '*keyword1*' 
    or keyword = '*keyword2*'
    or keyword = '*keyword3*'
```

But what I want is any `projectID` that matches all three keywords to be displayed first (if any), followed by the `projectID` that matched two out of three keywords, etc. `projectID` that don't have any matching keywords are not returned.

Example:

```
projectID  keyword 
---------  -------
 456       salsa
 456       guacamole
 456       tamale
 511       salsa
 511       tamale
 511       burrito
 511       taco
 654       margarita
 654       nachos
 789       margarita
 789       salsa  
 789       taco
```

For user keyword search for 'salsa','tamale','burrito', the query should return these projectID, in this order.

```
projectID
---------
 511          (matches all three)
 456          (matches two)
 789          (matches one)
```

How do I get the rows from the query returned in the specified order? (What query can I write to get that.)

Comment: What is application? What is the database? What have you tried so far? What didn't work? Provide more info.

Comment: [fulltext](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) + relevance score. Done.

Comment: When asking questions of this nature it's best to give a concrete example of the problem you're trying to solve. In this case a simplified schema would help considerably.

Comment: it is web application connected with mysql and I need an idea of how to order the search results

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow community! I think I understood what you were asking. I've edited your question significantly, to make the question a little narrower (asking a more specific question), and rewording the question to make it a little clearer, and give a concrete example data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
 SELECT k.projectID
   FROM project_keyword k
  WHERE k.keyword IN ('*keyword1*','*keyword2*','*keyword3*')
  GROUP BY k.projectID
  ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT k.keyword) DESC, k.projectID
```

(This assumes that the table contains multiple rows for a projectID, one row for each keyword. If that's not how the table is organized, if it's a single row, and you are looking for matching keywords that occur somewhere in a column, we'd need a different query.)

If you want to return the list of keywords that matched, you could use a `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate in the SELECT list

```
 SELECT k.projectID
      , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT k.keyword ORDER BY k.keyword) AS keywords_matched
   FROM ...
```